# Is there a free way to schedule posts from Facebook pages, the way that TweetDeck does with Twitter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, scheduling

Hootsuite isn't free as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Pages natively supports [post scheduling on a Page](https://www.facebook.com/help/389849807718635).

[Hootsuite is free](https://hootsuite.com/plans) for up to 3 social profiles.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com)'s free plan, you can also try [Buffer](http://bufferapp.com).

Comment: I've heard good things about Hootsuite, but Buffer has changed my life from scheduled to unscheduled for ALL social media (almost, they don't support Google+ profiles yet, but they do support pages)